# GitHub Markdown colspan

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

Is there a way to have `colspan` on GitHub Markdown?

I'm trying to create a table where one row takes up four columns.

```
| One     | Two        | Three   | Four          | 
| ------------- |-------------| ---------| ------------- |
| One                | Two               | Three          | Four                |

| One     | Two        | Three   | Four          | 
| ------------- |-------------| ---------| ------------- |
| Span Across ||||
```

You can see a live preview by pasting the above [here](http://markdown-here.com/livedemo.html).

Comment: Sorry to inform you, Markdown does not support colspan or rowspan.

Comment: [MultiMarkdown 4 supports colspan](http://fletcher.github.io/MultiMarkdown-4/tables), but it's not used on GitHub

Comment: Textile does both colspan and rowspan with a [consistent syntax](https://txstyle.org/doc/15/tables).

Answer (score 117):

You can use HTML tables on GitHub (but [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909) on StackOverflow)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Becomes

[image: HTML table output]

Answer (score 84):

Compromise minimum solution:

```
| One    | Two | Three | Four    | Five  | Six 
| -
| Span <td colspan=3>triple  <td colspan=2>double
```

So you can omit closing `</td>` for speed, оr can leave for consistency.

Result from http://markdown-here.com/livedemo.html :
[image: markdown table with colspan]

Works in Jupyter Markdown.

### Update:

As of 2019 year all pipes in the second line are compulsory in Jupyter Markdown.

```
| One    | Two | Three | Four    | Five  | Six
|-|-|-|-|-|-
| Span <td colspan=3>triple  <td colspan=2>double
```

minimally (does not work at Jupyter Lab):

```
One    | Two | Three | Four    | Five  | Six
-|||||-
Span <td colspan=3>triple  <td colspan=2>double
```

Comment: I got an issue with this solution if I try to use a colspan over the first column, a hack to avoid that in turn would be to add another first column that has no content... Yuck...

Comment: This does not work on GitHub, CommonMark nor StackOverflow

Comment: As of writing, this works on GitHub wikis.  However, GH doesn't know you've added extra columns, so it adds blank cells on the right.

Comment: I understood that Pipes are ether optional at the beginning and the end, or none of them. Maybe should you add one at the end of this lines?

Comment: How to make it works also for table header (it has two rows as header, where the first row has spanned column)? I have tried in Jupyter Notebook and it does not work.

Comment: I believe that the syntax supports the single row header, and does not supports thead and tbody tags as you want, I suppose. You can check in sources of markdown parser. Anyway this is not a speedy syntax anymore. Try emdebbed tables in header string (can omit the first <tr>): 
One    | <table><tr><th>Two upper</th></tr><tr><th>Two lower</th></tr></table> | <th colspan="2" bgcolor="red">Three tall | <table><th>Four upper</th><tr><th>Four lower</th></tr></table>    | Five  | Six
-|-|-|-|-|-
Span <td colspan=3>triple  <td colspan=2>double

Answer (score 24):

There is no way to do so.
Either use an HTML table, or put the same text on several cells.

like this:

```
| Can Reorder | 2nd operation |2nd operation |2nd operation |
| :---: | --- |
|1st operation|Normal Load <br/>Normal Store| Volatile Load <br/>MonitorEnter|Volatile Store<br/> MonitorExit|
|Normal Load <br/> Normal Store| | | No|
|Volatile Load <br/> MonitorEnter| No|No|No|
|Volatile store <br/> MonitorExit| | No|No|
```

which looks like

[image: HTML table]

Comment: use || for two column span use ||| for three column span and so on so forth

Answer (score 16):

I recently needed to do the same thing, and was pleased that the colspan worked fine with consecutive pipes ||

[image: MultiMarkdown v4.5]

Tested on v4.5 (latest on macports) and the v5.4 (latest on homebrew).  Not sure why it doesn't work on the live preview site you provide.

A simple test that I started with was:

```
| Header ||
|--------------|
| 0 | 1 |
```

using the command:

```
multimarkdown -t html test.md > test.html
```

Comment: That's not supported on github

Comment: Looks like a nice markup, I'd like to see it pick up adoption.