# Is there a way to colspan a table header with GitHub flavored markdown?

Tags: html-table, github-flavored-markdown

HTML allows extending a table's header row across multiple columns using `colspan`:

```html
<table>
  <tr><th colspan=2>Logical Operators</th></tr>
  <tr><td>&&</td><td>Logical and</td></tr>
  <tr><td>||</td><td>Logical or</td></tr>
  <tr><td>!</td><td>Logical not</td></tr>
  <tr><td>? :</td><td>Logical ternary</td></tr>
</table>
```

On GitHub, when this HTML is rendered in a readme.md file it looks like this:

[image]

...but [using markdown syntax to create a table](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/), I can't span the table's header row across columns, e.g. I can only split up the header text:

```
| Logical | Operators |
|:---:| --- |
| `&&` | Logical and |
| `\|\|` | Logical or |
| `!` | Logical not |
| `? :` | Logical ternary |
```

...and rendering the GFM table on GitHub looks like:

[image]

I tried emulating [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091054/5225057) for using `colspan` in the table's data rows, but I could not get it to work with the header row. Is there a way to span the [GFM table's](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables) header row across more than one column with GitHub flavored Markdown?

I've posted the question to the folks at the [GH MD repo](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1151).

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way in order to generate a table with 5 columns with headers spanning respectively over 3 and 2 columns:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan=3>a  <td colspan=2>b
<tr>
<td colspan=1>col1 <td colspan=1>col2 <td colspan=1>col3<td colspan=1>col4 <td colspan=1>col5
</table>
```

My two cents.