# Add table of contents to hyde-hyde theme in Hugo

Tags: hugo, hyde

I'm using the hyde-hyde theme for my website with Hugo (https://github.com/htr3n/hyde-hyde), and I can't figure out a way to add a table fo contents to my posts, especially the long ones. Is there a simple way to do it with this theme ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED 2018-09-30**:

I misread the original question about TOC and instead gave an answer on tables in Markdown.

Regarding *Table of Contents*, there are essentially two approaches:

a) Using [Hugo support for TOC](https://gohugo.io/content-management/toc) and add some CSS rules to style the TOC as you wish

b) Using external libraries such as [Tocbot](https://tscanlin.github.io/tocbot) that can scan the HTML content and extract the headings to create the TOC. Tocbot is very [powerful and configurable](https://tscanlin.github.io/tocbot/#api).

In particular in `hyde-hyde`, you can do the following the achieve a TOC:

a) Add `{{ .TableOfContents }}` to [*layouts/partials/page-single/content.html*](https://github.com/htr3n/hyde-hyde/blob/master/layouts/partials/page-single/content.html), for instance

```
{{ if .Site.Params.toc }}
    {{ .TableOfContents }}
{{ end }}
```

b) Style the original Hugo generated TOC with the root element `nav#TableOfContents`, for example

```
#TableOfContents > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#TableOfContents > ul > li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

You can investigate further the example code [here](https://github.com/htr3n/hyde-hyde/blob/master/assets/scss/hugo-toc.scss) where I developed a collapsible TOC.

---

I'm the author of `hyde-hyde`, so hopefully I can weigh in some suggestions.

`hyde-hyde` is a just theme used by [gohugo](https://gohugo.io) to generate static Web pages (HTML/CSS/JS) from Markdown (MD) contents. So what you need is to add tables in your Markdown files.

Note that tables are not specified in [original Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown) but supported in many variants like [MultiMarkdown (MMD)](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown) or [Github Flavored Markdown (GFM)](https://github.github.com/gfm).

Another potential approach is using inline HTML supported by Markdown to add `<table>...</table>` as you wish. This works better in case you need complex tables (e.g. with rowspan or colspan), as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23571724/339302).

The aforementioned methods can be used with other Hugo themes as well. Either way, Hugo can handle tables well.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to gohugo, so I can't provide precise support. But it seems like gohugo comes with a built-in system for adding tables of contents to posts. Here's the gohugo documentation for the feature: https://gohugo.io/content-management/toc/

I am not sure where and how the TOC would appear in a post published with the Hyde-Hyde theme. The author of the theme might have some insight there.