# How to use col span in markdown?

Tags: html-table, markdown, col

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571724/github-markdown-colspan) post I found out how do col span in mark down. Nevertheless if I use this:

```
| One     | Two        | Three   | Four          | 
| ------- | ---------- | ------- | ------------- |
| One     | Two        | Three   | Four          |

| One     | Two        | Three   | Four          | 
| ------- |----------- | ------- | ------------- |
| Span Across ||||
```

I get this from https://markdown-here.com/livedemo.html :

[image: failing col span in markdown]

**How to use col span in markdown?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are a non-standard feature of Markdown as they are not part of the original [rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Various Markdown implementations have implemented their own tables add-on. However, without a authoritative rule-set, they are not always consistent.

As you are using Markdown Here, you need to consult their [documentation](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet#tables), which makes no mention of any column span feature. However, the documentation does mention that the tables feature is copied from GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM). GFM has a full [spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-). If Markdown Here strictly follows that spec, then we can be confident in how it is to behave. However, I don't know if they do or not (the wording in the documentation does not inspire confidence in a strict match in behavior).

Regardless, GFM does not include support for column spans. Therefore, it is safe to assume that Markdown Here does not as well.