# Markdown table rowspan without loss of formatting

Tags: html, markdown

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390156/10444934) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091054/10444934) answers, we can use HTML tags in Markdown to create tables with cells spanning multiple rows or columns. Suppose I want to make the following table (rendered by Visual Studio Code with extension "Markdown All in One"):

[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3T8a.png)

But the problem for the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091054/10444934) is that the rowspan/colspan of the *first* column/row will be rendered with a additional column/row in the front, as in the following example (does not work on StackOverflow, but works in VSCode; a work-around is to add an empty column/row, as suggested by the first comment in that answer, but this is still not perfect):

```
||Letter|Typesetting|Result|
|-|-|-|-|
|<td rowspan=4>a |Normal|a
||Italic|*a*|
||Bold|**a**|
||Math|$a$
```

Result:

[Table constructed using method in Answer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJAoc.png)

Then we can use the HTML tags, as described by the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091054/10444934):

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>Letter <th>Typesetting <th>Result
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td rowspan=4>a <td>Normal <td>a
        <tr> <td>Italic <td>*a*
        <tr> <td>Bold <td>**a**
        <tr> <td>Math <td>$a$ 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But then Markdown formatting will be lost:

[Table constructed using method in Answer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUonT.png)

Is there any way to overcome this problem, i.e. using HTML tags to achieve rowspan/colspan without loss of Markdown text formatting?

Comment: No, I think there isn't.

Comment: Now possible using [pandoc grid tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables)...