# "booktabs" like tables for markdown

Tags: html, css, html-table, markdown

I'm customizing a css file for a Typora Markdown template. I would like to add horizontal lines to follow the formatting guidelines set by the LaTeX package [`booktabs`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf)

Essentially, all I would need is a thicker top-most line, a thicker bottom-most line, and a thin line under the header. Note that the partial line under Item is necessary (but it would be nice to understand how).

How would I modify the code below to offer a format for the image shown?

```css
table > thead > tr > th,
table > thead > tr > td,
table > tbody > tr > th,
table > tbody > tr > td,
table > tfoot > tr > th,
table > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I achieved a close approximation of LaTex table styling with the following HTML and CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

th:not(:empty) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-weight: 400;
}

thead:first-child th {
  text-align: center;
}

tbody tr td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Item</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Animal</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price ($)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Gnat</td>
      <td>per gram</td>
      <td>13.65</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>each</td>
      <td>0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gnu</td>
      <td>stuffed</td>
      <td>92.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emu</td>
      <td>stuffed</td>
      <td>33.33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Armadillo</td>
      <td>frozen</td>
      <td>8.99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some reasonable CSS that matches your described goal:

```css
    /* Make horizontal lines connect through column boundaries */
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    /* General styling of all cells */
    table > :is(thead, tbody) > tr > :is(th, td) {
      padding: 3px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    table > thead > tr > :is(th, td) {
      border-top: 2px solid; /* Top thick line */
      border-bottom: 1px solid; /* Below head thin line */
    }
    table > tbody > tr:last-child > :is(th, td) {
      border-bottom: 2px solid; /* Bottom thick line */
    }
```

To demo this, I made this Markdown table:

```markdown
| Animal | Description | Price |
|--------|-------------|------:|
| Gnat   | per gram    | 13.65 |
|        | each        |  0.01 |
| Gnu    | stuffed     | 92.50 |
| Emu    | stuffed     | 33.33 |
| Armadillo | frozen   |  8.99 |
```

It renders on StackOverflow here as the following HTML:

| Animal | Description | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gnat | per gram | 13.65 |
|  | each | 0.01 |
| Gnu | stuffed | 92.50 |
| Emu | stuffed | 33.33 |
| Armadillo | frozen | 8.99 |

Now taking that HTML and adding CSS styling to it, we get this demo:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table > :is(thead, tbody) > tr > :is(th, td) {
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
}
table > thead > tr > :is(th, td) {
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
table > tbody > tr:last-child > :is(th, td) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="s-table"><thead>
<tr>
<th>Animal</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th style="text-align:right">Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Gnat</td>
<td>per gram</td>
<td style="text-align:right">13.65</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>each</td>
<td style="text-align:right">0.01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gnu</td>
<td>stuffed</td>
<td style="text-align:right">92.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Emu</td>
<td>stuffed</td>
<td style="text-align:right">33.33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Armadillo</td>
<td>frozen</td>
<td style="text-align:right">8.99</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[It's not possible to do multi-column cells in Markdown tables, but there are workarounds.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571724/github-markdown-colspan)  It's also not possible to do multiple header rows, I'm afraid.  But you could probably manually embed a `<table>` with your own `<thead>` and `<td colspan=2>` and so on.  (I tried Typora Markdown briefly, but couldn't figure out how to use it well, so I don't know exactly what it supports.)