# Markdown: how to split a cell in a table

Tags: markdown, github-pages

G'evening.
I'm doing a page for a lab work report at the GitHub and I have to do a table similar to this using "Markdown":
[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrMmO.png)

How can I split a cell into 8 cells like it is done in the second (2) row of that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub does not support this feature using pure markdown syntax. It does, however, support HTML tables as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390156/3298175). You would have to use the `colspan` attribute on the `<td>` tag to tell how many columns that cell should span. Don't see it as *splitting* a cell, but more like *merging* multiple cells.

It all boils down to whatever markdown processor you are using. Some *do* support markdown syntax for table cells to span multiple columns, and on the other hand, not all markdown processors support HTML syntax.